# Дружественность шаблонных классов при совпадении параметров

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Нужно что бы один шаблонный класс становился дружественным другому шаблонному классу только при совпадении типов параметров

```
template <class T>
class A {
private:
   int var;

template <class>
friend class B;
};

template <class T>
class B {
public:
   void f(A<double> a) {
       cout << a.var << endl;
   }
};

B<double> b1;
b1.f(A<double>());// B и A имеют одну и ту же специализацию (double) - дружественность должна сработать 

B<int> b2;
b2.f(A<double>()); //B и A имеют разные специализации (int и double) - дружественность должна НЕ сработать
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//Объявление шаблона класса
template <class>
class B;

template <class T>
class A {
private:
   int var;

friend class B<T>;//Дружественная специализация
};
```